# Multiple true condition in ifelse command

Tags: r

In R we use *ifelse(test, yes, no)* command. The problem which i am facing is if a codiation comes out to be true i need to perform various statement, for example

ifelse(fp$month==1,(fp$sum(sales_1),fp$sum(sales_2)),0)

So I am giving two condition if fp$month = 1.those conditions are **sum(fp$sales_1),sum(fp$sales_2)**, but R is recognising second comma. How to give multiple true condiations?

the example is

```
a <- "01" 
b <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6) 
c <- c(12,13,1234,1334,23) 
d <- ifelse(a=="01",(sum(b),sum(c)),0)
```

here i want if the "a" value is "01" then i want sum of vector b and c. but i am getting error :-

```
Error: unexpected ',' in "d <- ifelse(a=="01",(sum(b),"_
```

The expected output is :-
`[1] 21 2616`

Comment: May be you need `rep` i.e. `ifelse(rep(a,2)=='01', c(sum(b), sum(c)), 0)`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This works:

```
a <- "01" 
ifelse(a=="01", d <- c(sum(b),sum(c)), d <- 0)
d
#[1]   21 2616

a <- "02"
ifelse(a=="01", d <- c(sum(b),sum(c)), d <-0)
d
#[1] 0
```

Comment: Don't use `ifelse` like this. It's intended for vector input. Use `d <- if(a=="01") c(sum(b),sum(c)) else 0` instead.

Comment: Why not submit this as an answer, @Roland?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the & ('and') statement.
You also need to alocate the sum to the variable, like this:

```
a <- "01" 
b <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6) 
c <- c(12,13,1234,1334,23) 
d <- ifelse(a=="01",( (b <- sum(b)) & (c <- sum(c)) ),0)
```