# if else statement concatenation - R

Tags: r, if-statement

This is a very common question: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368145/multiple-true-condition-in-ifelse-command), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871653/chaining-if-else-with-multiple-do-statements-in-r), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45335908/how-to-chain-ifelse-statement-in-dplyr), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31261946/multiple-if-statements-in-r), [5](https://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-chain-ifelse-statements-in-r/), and still I cannot find even an answer to my problem.

```
If a == 1, then do X.
If a == 0, then do Y.
If a == 0 and b == 1, then do Z.
```

Just to explain: the if else statements has to do `Y` if `a==0` no matter the value of `b`. But if `b == 1` and `a == 0`, `Z` will do additional changes to those already done by `Y`.

My current code and its error:

```
if (a == 1){
X
} else if(a == 0){
Y
} else if (a == 0 & b == 1){ 
Z}

Error in !criterion : invalid argument type
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `else` only happens if a previous `if` **hasn't happened**.

When you say

> But if `b == 1` and `a == 0`, `Z` will do additional changes to those already done by `Y`

Then you have two options:

```
## Option 1: nest Z inside Y
if (a == 1){
  X
} else if(a == 0){
  Y
  if (b == 1){ 
    Z
  }
}


## Option 2: just use `if` again (not `else if`):
if (a == 1) {
  X
} else if(a == 0) {
  Y
}

if (a == 0 & b == 1) {  
  Z
}
```

Really, you don't need any `else` here at all.

```
## This will work just as well 
## (assuming that `X` can't change the value of a from 1 to 0
if (a == 1) {
  X
}

if (a == 0) {
  Y
  if (b == 1){ 
    Z
  }
}
```

Typically `else` is needed when you want to have a "final" action that is done only if none of the previous `if` options were used, for example:

```
# try to guess my number between 1 and 10
if (your_guess == 8) {
  print("Congratulations, you guessed my number!")
} else if (your_guess == 7 | your_guess = 9) {
  print("Close, but not quite") 
} else {
  print("Wrong. Not even close!")
}
```

In the above, `else` is useful because I don't want to have enumerate all the other possible guesses (or even bad inputs) that a user might enter. If they guess 8, they win. If they guess 7 or 9, I tell them they were close. Anything else, no matter what it is, I just say "wrong".

**Note:** this is true for programming languages in general. It is not unique to R.

However, since this is in the R tag, I should mention that R has `if{}else{}` and `ifelse()`, and they are different.

- `if{}` (and optionally `else{}`) evaluates a single condition, and you can run code to do *anything* in `{}` depending on that condition.
- `ifelse()` is a vectorized function, it's arguments are `test`, `yes`, `no`. The `test` evaluates to a boolean vector of TRUE and FALSE values. The `yes` and `no` arguments *must be vectors of the same length as `test`*. The result will be a vector of the same length as `test`, with the corresponding values of `yes` (when `test` is TRUE) and `no` (when `test` is FALSE).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to include Z in the second condition like this:

```
if (a == 1){X}
else if(a == 0){
    Y
    if (b == 1){Z}
}
```